# Connection with SQL Server: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, visual-studio-code

I am trying to connect a little Java App to a SQL Server database using Visual Studio Code. This is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionUrl =
                "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-03898L2DB;"
                        + "Database=DB_PA;"
                        + "User=checkou-GN;"
                        + "Password=sapassword;"
                        + "IntegratedSecurity=true;"
                        + "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
            ;
            try {
                //String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
                //Class.forName(driver);
                try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);) {
                
                System.out.println("Connected");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

But when I run it I get this message:

```
cd "c:\Users\checki\Desktop\JAVA\pruebaN3\prueba\src\" && javac App.java && java App
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-033L2DB;Database=DB_PA;User=checkou-GN;Password=sapassword;IntegratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at App.main(App.java:16)
```

I've succesfully imported the connectors and the SDK as shown in the picture:

[image]

The thing is that I've tried to do the same on another computer and it seems to work fine:

[image: Working case on another machine]

The main difference for me is the command that the shell is executing: in the first case is using javac and java and in the working case is using:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\bin\java.exe' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '@C:\Users\sempr\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_9hxr1t8qo8sc8hiaiyq1qpyf9.argfile' 'App'
```

I don't know what the problem could be and I've tried almost everything. In Eclipse and Intelij the program works fine on both machines but with VSCode in the first machine does not work.

Comment: Looks like you don't have sql-server jar file in classpath.

Comment: You are passing the Username and password but also have `IntegratedSecurity=true`; these conflict. You either are using Integrated Security (Windows Authentication) or you pass the username and password and are using SQL Authentication.

Comment: @user16320675 The users, passwords and names are not real ;). I've changed them for the screenshots. So yes, it is a dummy password, the server is not public and there are no data, it is a dummy DB too :D

Comment: @PradeepSimha So, I have to add the route to the jar file in the PATH variable, right?

Comment: @Larnu I've removed it but the problem it is still there. The same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Code Runner` for the first case? Please choose `Run Java` button instead of `Run Code` button. The `Code Runner` will not find the referenced libraries.